# How to customize the layout of login page in joomla

Tags: joomla

Just want change the layout of the login page same as other pages, I want to remove the left sidebar bar and show the main menu, few images and text. You can see the current layout.
Visit http://www.egovtsolutions.net/index.php/component/users/?view=login

Answer (score 0):

You can make the menu module display on all pages rather than on selected pages...then the menu will be displayed on all pages.

Answer (score 0):

You have to choose display option from that module. If you want to enable some modules in that position just check the menus names from that module.

If you don't want any module in login page just unselect all modules from that page. Then only you have better look for login prompt as your wish.

Try this....

Answer (score 0):

I dont know which version of joomla are you working on. But this [link](http://www.artisteer.com/?p=help_joomla) covers from joomla 1.5 to 1.7.

You should try to give the "extra2" or "position-29" to your *log in* module.

The key is just the position you are assigning.